# GWT JavaScriptObject: get original json string?

Tags: javascript, json, gwt, jsonp

I have been working with JSONP on my GWT application. When my server sends a json string, I can get it in the form of a JavaScriptObject on the client side.

My problem is my json has complicated structures: using maps, nests with a lot of different keys. That is a big pain to extract data (I may have to write few hundred functions for all keys to extract data one by one and some complicated codes to fill maps).

I am considering few solutions:

- Encode and send whole json strings as normal strings to client (as a value of a simple json string). Just worry my encoded strings may be few time longer than the original ones and may easily exceed the limit of 2k long
- Convert back a JavaScriptObject into a pure string (similar to one I sent from the server)

After having a pure string I will parse it using some json parsers / methods to the structures I feel convenient.

My questions:

1) How to convert back a JavaScriptObject object into a pure / original json string?

2) Any idea about solutions?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Convert JavaScriptObject to JSON: `JsonUtils.stringify(yourJSO)`
   Convert JSON to JavaScriptObject: `JsonUtils.safeEval(jsonString);`

2) Did you think about using AutoBeans?? [Check out the GWT page](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideAutoBeans.html)